# Remove all occurrences of several chars from a string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, built-in

Is there a pythonic way to do what the [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method does, except for *all* occurrences, not just those at the beginning and end of a string?

Example:

```
>> '::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'.strip(' -.:')
>> '2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000'
```

I want

```
>> '::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'.crazy_function(' -.:')
>> '20120514181020856000'
```

Does Python provides me a built-in `crazy_function`???

I could easily do it programatically, but I want to know if there is a built-in for that.
Couldn't find one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) function to delete the unwanted characters:

```
>>> '::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'.translate(None, ' -.:')
'20120514181020856000'
```

Be sure your string is of `str` type and not `unicode`, as the parameters of the function won't be the same. For unicode, use the following syntax ; it consists in building the dict of unicode ordinals from the chars to delete and to map them to `None`:

```
>>> u'::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'.translate({ord(k):None for k in u' -.:'})
u'20120514181020856000'
```

Some timings for performance comparison with `re`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("""re.sub(r"[ -.:]", r"", "'::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'")""","import re")
7.352270301875713
>>> timeit.timeit("""'::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'.translate(None, ' -.:')""")
0.5894893344550951
```

Comment: I prefer a builtin solution like this over the solution written by Nick Craig-Wood. But I wonder: In terms of performance, what's better? I could be wrong, but this 'translate' function probably makes use of regexp functionality.

Comment: @Francisco: I guess there are actually two different translate functions. The 3-arugment version works with _byte sequences_, it uses a translation table, which is lighting fast. The unicode version works on _strings_, it replaces characters one-by-one and is actually just as slow as the regexp if not slower. I'd still use regular expressions for your problem, because mixing _strings_ and _byte sequences_ is never a good idea, even in python2.

Comment: @thg435: In my problem speifically the byte version is just fine. I am creating id codes based on str(datetime.datetime.now()) and adding an extra piece of string to it. So, unicode is not a problem for me.

Comment: @Francisco: if you're creating these strings in your code, why don't you simply use strftime?

Comment: @thg435: just checked strftime, it's twice faster to do the trick above from str(now()) rather than now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')

Comment: @thg435 That didn't even occured to me! But I must confess, I was surprised by the fact that a string substitution operation is twice as slow as a parse to string PLUS a translate() call.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it easily enough with `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"[ -.:]", r"", "'::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'")
'20120514181020856000'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

No. I don't think there is a built in.

I would do it this way:

```
>>> s = '::2012-05-14 18:10:20.856000::'
>>> 
>>> ''.join(x for x in s if x not in ' -.:')
'20120514181020856000'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's "programatically".

Comment: Look at the other answer that uses translate